# I need to get the Substring from a column , which function can be best suitable for it?

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

```
Entity=10||WorkdayReferenceID=9000100102||HCMCostCenterMgr=svigeant@broadinstitute.org||FRP=100007071||BGType=Organizational||SalAllow=Y||ConcurAtlasAllow=Y||EBAllow=Y||
```

Can someone help I need to extract the **`FRP`** value from it .

For ex - The output should be "**`100007071`**"

```
RTRIM(NVL(SUBSTR(TL.DESCRIPTION,(INSTR(TL.DESCRIPTION, '=' ,1,4)+1)
                               ,(INSTR(TL.DESCRIPTION, '||',1,4)-1)),0), '|')
```

I tried this but not getting the result.

Answer (score 2):

One option uses `REGEXP_REPLACE()` such as

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'(.*FRP=)(\d+)(.*)','\2') AS result       
  FROM t

RESULT
---------
100007071
```

which extracts the piece starting just after `FRP=` and goes as long as the digits(`\d+`) persist

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1FC08B0p)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Entity=10||WorkdayReferenceID=9000100102||HCMCostCenterMgr=svigeant@broadinstitute.org||FRP=100007071||BGType=Organizational||SalAllow=Y||ConcurAtlasAllow=Y||EBAllow=Y||' from dual)
```

Query:

```
  3  select ltrim(regexp_substr(col, 'FRP=\d+'), 'FRP=') result
  4  from test
  5  /

RESULT
---------
100007071

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have or don't want regexp (performace costly) it could be done with SubStr() And InStr() functions.

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
      (  Select 'Entity=10||WorkdayReferenceID=9000100102||HCMCostCenterMgr=svigeant@broadinstitute.org||FRP=100007071||BGType=Organizational||SalAllow=Y||ConcurAtlasAllow=Y||EBAllow=Y||' "MY_TEXT" From Dual  )

Select  SubStr( SubStr(MY_TEXT, InStr(MY_TEXT, '||FRP=') + 6), 
                1,
                InStr(SubStr(MY_TEXT, InStr(MY_TEXT, '||FRP=') + 6), '||', 1, 1) - 1
              ) "FRP"
From tbl

FRP      
---------
100007071
```